std::unordered_map insert, emplace and [] is calling copy constructor or copy assignment instead of move constructor or move assignment
OS: vxWorks 7
C++ Standard: 17
Compiler: Clang16
I created an object of a class (FCS) which creates and works on POSIX timers. Once all operations on the FCS class are completed, I wish to insert it into an unordered_map (std::unordered_map<track_id_t, FCS> mHardKill) which will maintained and operated henceforth.
Whenever I try to insert or emplace or use operator[], the copy constructor is only called. I wish to move the FCS object.
I create and start the timer while working on FCS object but when I insert the object to std::unordered_map, copy constructor is called. The timer is not copied and at the same time the destructor is called on the original object the timer is destroyed.
I tried all below methods to insert but I get the same result.
mHardKill[trackId] = f;
mHardKill[trackId] = std::move(f);
mHardKill.insert({trackId, t});
mHardKill.insert(std::make_pair(trackId, f));
mHardKill.emplace(std::make_pair(trackId, f));
mHardKill.insert(std::make_pair(trackId, std::move(f)));
mHardKill.emplace(std::make_pair(trackId, std::move(f)));

How do I resolve this? Do I have to create a dedicated move constructor? How can I have the timer object without destroying the current instance of timer?
Main application
std::unordered_map<track_id_t, FCS> mHardKill;

FCS f(trackId);
... //Some other operations
f.mTimeToLaunchMicroseconds = 1500; //1.5 milli-seconds
f.timer.start(PosixTimer::in_microseconds(mTimeToLaunchMicroseconds));
mHardKill[trackId] = f;
mHardKill[trackId] = std::move(f);
mHardKill.insert({trackId, t});
mHardKill.insert(std::make_pair(trackId, f));
mHardKill.emplace(std::make_pair(trackId, f));
mHardKill.insert(std::make_pair(trackId, std::move(f)));
mHardKill.emplace(std::make_pair(trackId, std::move(f)));

fcs.hpp
class FCS
{
public:
    ~FCS();
    FCS(track_id_t trackId);
    FCS(const FCS&) = delete;//Added to check if the FCS object is copied or moved in std::unordered_map
    FCS& operator= (const FCS&) = delete;//Added to check if the FCS object is copied or moved in std::unordered_map
    PosixTimer timer;
    std::uint64_t mTimeToLaunchMicroseconds;
    track_id_t trackId;        
    void timer_callback(const std::any &data);
    bool startTimer(bool newTrack);
    std::any timerCallbackData;
};

fcs.cpp
FCS::~FCS()
{
    std::cerr << "FCS destructor Called\n";
    this->timer.stop();
    this->timer.destroy();
}

FCS::FCS(track_id_t trackId)
{

    this->trackId = trackId;
    this->timerCallbackData = std::make_any<TimerOperation>(TimerOperation::None);
    this->timer.registerCallback(std::bind(&FCS::timer_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1), timerCallbackData);
    this->timer.create();
}

// called when the timer for firing command elapses
void FCS::timer_callback(const std::any &data)
{
    //Do something
}

bool FCS::startTimer(bool newTrack)
{
    if (newTrack == true) // track not found in mTracks                                                                      // track not found
    {
        this->timer.start(PosixTimer::in_microseconds(static_cast<std::uint64_t>(this->mTimeToLaunchMicroseconds)));
    }
    else if (newTrack == false) // track found in mTracks
    {
        this->timer.update(PosixTimer::in_microseconds(static_cast<std::uint64_t>(this->mTimeToLaunchMicroseconds)));
    }
    return true;
}

PosixTimer.hpp
#pragma once

#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

//#include <timerLib.h>

typedef int signal_t;

class PosixTimer
{
public:
    static bool initialize(void);
    static inline const int signal_rt_min = SIGRTMIN, signal_rt_max = SIGRTMAX;
    using callback_timer_t = std::function<void(const std::any&)>;
    PosixTimer(callback_timer_t callback, const std::any& callback_data, 
        bool periodic = false) : PosixTimer(periodic)
    {
        this->callback = callback;
        this->callback_data = callback_data;
    }
    PosixTimer(bool periodic);
    PosixTimer();

    ~PosixTimer();
    bool create(void);//Create timer only
    bool create(std::uint64_t timeout, bool periodic);//Initialize the Periodic Timer Object, Create timer, set timeout and start timer
    bool create(std::uint64_t timeout);//Create timer, set timeout and start timer
    bool update(std::uint64_t timeout);//Stop timer, update set timeout and start timer
    bool start(std::uint64_t timeout);//Set timeout and start timer
    bool start(void);//Starts the timer with the timeout value (refer private timeout variables)
    bool stop(void);//Stops the timer
    bool destroy(void);//Destroys the timer. Can't be reused without calling create
    void registerCallback(callback_timer_t callback, const std::any& callback_data);

    static std::uint64_t in_nanoseconds(std::uint64_t timeout);
    static std::uint64_t in_microseconds(std::uint64_t timeout);
    static std::uint64_t in_milliseconds(std::uint32_t timeout);
    static std::uint64_t in_seconds(std::uint16_t timeout);
private:
    static inline std::map<signal_t, bool>  signal_usage_status;
    signal_t                    signal_id;
    static inline std::uint8_t  total_timer_count = 0;
    std::uint8_t                timer_count = 0;
    bool                        periodic;
    std::uint64_t               timeout;// in nano-seconds
    timer_t                     timer_id;
    sigset_t                    mask;
    std::any                    callback_data;
    struct sigevent             sev;
    struct sigaction            sa;
    struct itimerspec           its;
    static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc);
    callback_timer_t            callback;
    bool                        block_signal(void);
    bool                        unblock_signal(void);
};

class SignalNumberExhausted : public std::exception
{
private:
    static inline const std::string message = "Real-time signal number exhausted"; 
public:
    SignalNumberExhausted() {}
    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};

PosixTimer.cpp
#include "posix_timer.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#define CLOCK_ID CLOCK_REALTIME

bool PosixTimer::initialize(void)
{
    try
    {   
        for(int i = PosixTimer::signal_rt_min; i <= PosixTimer::signal_rt_max; i++)
        {
            // std::cout << i << std::endl;
            PosixTimer::signal_usage_status[i] = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        // Log Error
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return false;
    }
}

PosixTimer::PosixTimer()
{}


PosixTimer::PosixTimer(bool periodic)
{
    this->periodic = periodic;
    this->timer_count = SIGRTMIN + PosixTimer::total_timer_count++;
    // NativePosixTimer::total_timer_count++;
    bool signal_assigned = false;
    for (auto& [key, value]: PosixTimer::signal_usage_status)
    {
        if(value == false)//Timer not assigned
        {
            this->signal_id = key; //Assign the free signal 
            value = true;
            signal_assigned = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(signal_assigned == false)
    {
        // std::cout << "In PosixTimer-> If\n";
        throw SignalNumberExhausted();
    }
}

PosixTimer::~PosixTimer()
{
    if(this->destroy() == false)
    {
        //Fog Error
    }
//  
}

bool PosixTimer::create(void)
{
    int returnValue;
    std::cerr<<"TIMER CREATE CALLED VOID, Timer ID:"<<this->timer_id<<std::endl;
    //Added by IK on 06-04-2024
    this->periodic = false;
    this->timer_count = SIGRTMIN + PosixTimer::total_timer_count++;
    // NativePosixTimer::total_timer_count++;
    bool signal_assigned = false;
    for (auto& [key, value]: PosixTimer::signal_usage_status)
    {
        if(value == false)//Timer not assigned
        {
            this->signal_id = key; //Assign the free signal 
            value = true;
            signal_assigned = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(signal_assigned == false)
    {
        // std::cout << "In Create-> If\n";
        throw SignalNumberExhausted();
    }
    //End of Addition by IK on 06-04-2024
    
    // Establish handler for timer signal.
    this->sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;

    sigemptyset(&this->sa.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(this->signal_id, &this->sa, nullptr) == -1)
    {
        // Log Error
        perror("sigaction in PosixCreate ");
        return false;
    }
    // Block timer signal temporarily.
    if (this->block_signal() == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Create a timer
    this->sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL; // Upon timer expiration, generate the signal sigev_signo for the process.
    this->sev.sigev_signo = this->signal_id;
    this->sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = this;
    returnValue = timer_create(CLOCK_ID, &this->sev, &this->timer_id);
    // std::cout << "Timer Create Return Value : " << returnValue << std::endl;
    if (returnValue == -1)
    {
        // Log Error
        perror("timer_create");
        return false;
    }
    // # -> Used with o, x or X specifiers the value is preceeded with 0, 0x or 0X respectively for values different than zero.
    // j -> The length sub-specifier modifies the length of the data type : uintmax_t
    // std::printf("timer ID is %#jx\n", (uintmax_t)timer_id); // Only for testing

    return true;
}

//bool PosixTimer::create(std::uint64_t timeout)
//{
//  bool return_status = this->create();
//  if (return_status == false)
//  {
//      return false;
//  }
//  return this->start(timeout);
//}

bool PosixTimer::create(std::uint64_t timeout, bool periodic)
{
    std::cerr<<"TIMER CREATE CALLED PARAMETRIZED, Timer ID:"<<this->timer_id<<std::endl;
    this->periodic = periodic;
    this->timer_count = SIGRTMIN + PosixTimer::total_timer_count++;
    // NativePosixTimer::total_timer_count++;
    bool signal_assigned = false;
    for (auto& [key, value]: PosixTimer::signal_usage_status)
    {
        if(value == false)//Timer not assigned
        {
            this->signal_id = key; //Assign the free signal 
            value = true;
            signal_assigned = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(signal_assigned == false)
    {
        // std::cout << "In Create-> If\n";
        throw SignalNumberExhausted();
    }

    bool return_status = this->create();

    if (return_status == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return this->start(timeout);
}

bool PosixTimer::update(std::uint64_t timeout)
{
    std::cerr<<"TIMER UPDATE CALLED, Timer ID:"<<this->timer_id<<std::endl;
    bool return_status = this->stop();
    
    if (return_status == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return this->start(timeout);
}

bool PosixTimer::start(std::uint64_t timeout)
{
    // std::cout << "In start: " << static_cast<float> (timeout) << std::endl;
    this->its.it_value.tv_sec = timeout / 1000000000;
    this->its.it_value.tv_nsec = timeout % 1000000000;
//   std::cerr << "Sec: " << this->its.it_value.tv_sec << "\t" << "nsec: " << this->its.it_value.tv_nsec << "\n";
    if (periodic == true)
    {
        this->its.it_interval.tv_sec = this->its.it_value.tv_sec;
        this->its.it_interval.tv_nsec = this->its.it_value.tv_nsec;
    }
    else
    {
        this->its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        this->its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    }
    return this->start();
}

bool PosixTimer::start(void)
{
    std::cerr<<"TIMER START CALLED, Timer ID:"<<this->timer_id<<std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Timer Value Sec: " << this->its.it_value.tv_sec << "\t" << "nsec: " << this->its.it_value.tv_nsec << "\n";
    std::cerr << "Timer Interval Value nSec: " << this->its.it_interval.tv_sec << "\t" << "nsec: " << this->its.it_interval.tv_nsec << "\n";
    int return_status = timer_settime(this->timer_id, 0, &this->its, nullptr);
    if (return_status == -1)
    {
        // TODO Log Error
        perror("PosixTimer::start->timer_settime");
        return false;
    }
    // TODO Remove in final code
    // std::cout << "Timer Started\n";
    this->unblock_signal();
    return true;
}

bool PosixTimer::stop(void)
{
    std::cerr<<"TIMER STOP CALLED, Timer ID:"<<this->timer_id<<std::endl;
    this->block_signal();
    struct itimerspec its;
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    int return_status = timer_settime(this->timer_id, 0, &its, nullptr);
    if (return_status == -1)
    {
        // TODO Log Error
        perror("PosixTimer::stop->timer_settime");
        return false;
    }
    // TODO Remove in final code
    // std::cout << "Timer Stopped\n";
    return true;
}

bool PosixTimer::destroy(void)
{
    int return_status = timer_delete(this->timer_id);
    if (return_status == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        PosixTimer::signal_usage_status.at(this->signal_id) = false;
        return true;
    }
}

void PosixTimer::registerCallback(callback_timer_t callback, const std::any& callback_data)
{
    this->callback_data = callback_data;
    this->callback = callback;
}

void PosixTimer::handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    // std::cout << "Handler Called\n";
    PosixTimer *timer = reinterpret_cast<PosixTimer *>(si->si_value.sival_ptr);
    timer->callback(timer->callback_data);
}

bool PosixTimer::block_signal(void)
{
    // Block timer signal temporarily.
#ifdef NDEBUG
    printf("Blocking signal %d\n", this->signal_id);
#endif

    // Empty a signal set
    if (sigemptyset(&this->mask) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaddset");
        return false;
    }
    // Add a signal to a signal set
    if (sigaddset(&this->mask, this->signal_id) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaddset");
        return false;
    }
    // Change the signal mask of the calling thread
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &this->mask, nullptr) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigprocmask");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool PosixTimer::unblock_signal(void)
{
    // std::printf("Unblocking signal %d\n", this->signal_id);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &this->mask, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("timer start- sigprocmask");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

std::uint64_t PosixTimer::in_milliseconds(std::uint32_t timeout)
{
    return timeout * 1000000ul;
}

std::uint64_t PosixTimer::in_nanoseconds(std::uint64_t timeout)
{
    return timeout;
}

std::uint64_t PosixTimer::in_microseconds(std::uint64_t timeout)
{
    return timeout * 1000ul;
}

std::uint64_t PosixTimer::in_seconds(std::uint16_t timeout)
{
    return timeout * 1000000000ul;
}


Perhaps you need to actually declare and define the "move" constructor and assignment operator? std::move doesn't do what you might think it does.

Your FCS class doesn't even have a move constructor. And do you really want FCS to have a std::any member?

I've not implemented dedicated move constructor. How do I implement move constructor without destroying the timer object for the current instance of timer. The FCS destructor needs to have timer destroy functionality as requirement.

Having a user-defined copy constructor inhibits the generation of a default move constructor. (And deleted counts as user-defined.) The same applies to the assignment operator.

@molbdnilo I manually deleted user-defined copy constructor as insert, emplace and operator[] where copying object instead of moving object. I was facing the same issue.

@DarkSorrow I think you misunderstood. A deleted one is "user-defined". The principle is that if the generated default copying is not appropriate, the default moving is probably also inappropriate, so it's not generated.

FCS is not moveable regardless of deleteing the copy constructor/assignment. As soon as you define ~FCS, the move is no longer default created. There's many rules around when things are no longer defaulted.

@molbdnilo Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

@ChrisMM Will implement move constructor in PosixTimer class and continue implementing move constructor in other classes.

Read about the Rule of 0/3/5

Unrelated, but this seems weird: mHardKill.emplace(std::make_pair(trackId, std::move(f)));. Use mHardKill.emplace(trackId, std::move(f));

@ChrisMM I was trying all possible combinations.  Which is the preferred mechanism?

I prefer emplace (when possible), and not using make_pair. Emplace constructs in-place, so generally should be used. make_pair would make a pair, then move the pair (I think, someone can correct me if I'm wrong). Emplace without it would just construct.

Note on spelling per previous edits: bellow and below are not the same word. Nearly always here you want "below" (meaning underneath).

If you implement one of the Big Five manually, the compiler leaves the rest to you. You won't get any default implementation anymore.
That doesn't mean you should never implement one yourself. If you need to free resources, the compiler won't implement that for you so you must implement that yourself.
In this case class FCS adds FCS::~FCS() therefore none of: FCS::FCS(const FCS&), FCS& FCS::operator=(const FCS&), FCS::FCS(FCS&&) nor FCS& FCS::operator=(FCS&&) will exist on class FCS unless you implement them.

I wish to move the FCS object.

A possible implementation for that will be: [1]
FCS::FCS(FCS&& other)
{
    *this = std::move(other);
}

FCS& FCS::operator=(FCS&& other)
{
    this->timer                     = std::move(other.timer);
    this->mTimeToLaunchMicroseconds = std::move(other.mTimeToLaunchMicroseconds);
    this->trackId                   = std::move(other.trackId);
    this->timerCallbackData         = std::move(other.timerCallbackData);
    return *this;
}
This implementation will work iff all data members that were std::moved have move implementations. [2]
Unfortunately PosixTimer doesn't and I can't confirm if track_id_t does. Every object that will be move assigned must have move assignment implementation. [3]

[1] I only gave a possible implementation for move and not copy because of the OP's statement and the OP went to an extent by deleteing the copy constructor and copy assignment operator. This is not even neccessary because not creating them at all is enough. They simply won't exist!
[2] I will keep saying "move" to avoid confusion even though it doesn't mean what it sounds like. std::move is exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an rvalue reference type.
[3] Remember the rule of five.
